# ng-model doesnt work for select option tags

Tags: angularjs

I have a  multiple select tags that displays a list of options, these select tags will be initialized with a some value defined in an array, but it seems that ng-model didn't work in my case, here is my code :

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <select 
            ng-model="choice.competence.codeCompetence"
            ng-options="competence.id as competence.titre group by competence.group for competence in competences track by competence.id"> <input type="text" ng-model="choice.niveauRequis"> Ans --- Selected option : {{choice.competence.codeCompetence}}
            </select>
        </div>
```

And this is a jsfiddle to understand my problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/3628/

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: You should choice the expressions, or `as` or `track by`, not both. From [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions): *"Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression."*. Also, `ng-repeat` creates a `child scope`, so you can have some problems with `ngModel`. Always use the `dot rule` or `controller as syntax`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shammelburg/qWzTb/3631/)

I removed `track by competence.id` and this seems to work fine.

Your `competences` array has the `id` property so your `track by` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You must choose between the `as` *syntax* or `track by` *expression*. Using them together brings several problems.

From [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

> *"Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression."*

Also, `ng-repeat` creates a `child scope`, so you can have some problems with `ngModel`. Always use the `dot rule` or `controller as syntax`.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/3632/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks but it seems that the select tags are always empty in the given demo

Comment: What do you want to mean by "*are always empty*"?

Comment: I mean that the select tag is not populated with the value : http://i.stack.imgur.com/KBTBU.png

Comment: Hmm, so you want a `ngModel` only with `id`? Then, just remove the `track by` and use `as` syntax. Just never together.